# Mule Soft Data Weave

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

I want to write a Data Weave Code wherein if the data is null then it should route to 400. How do I write this in Mule Soft?

My flow is as follows:
HTTP -->Transfomer-->Logger

Tranformer DW code
{
    event_ops_type: payload.EDM_generic_consumer_message.event_meta_data.event_operation_type
}

Now what I want to implement is if "event_ops_type" is null then  route to 400(Exception Handling)?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using a validation module. MuleSoft documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/validation/validation-connector).

```xml
<validation:is-not-null message="event_ops_type is null!" value="#[flowVars.event_ops_type]" exceptionClass="com.example.MyException" doc:name="Validation"/>
```

You can also use a Groovy script in a choice block to throw any exception you'd like. Here, it will actually throw a 404 with the API generated exception handling. You could switch this to any exception you'd like.

```xml
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[flowVars.event_ops_type != null]">
        <logger message="#[flowVars.event_ops_type]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException(flowVars['event_ops_type'] + " is null!"); ]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
<exception-strategy ref="api-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
```

Comment: I tried the second method ,by using Groovy Component : I have the following query 1. How will the script written in Groovy redirect the flow to "Reference Exception Strategy"

Comment: Using a choice router with scripting is not ideal. It accomplishes the same thing as the validation component but requires much more code. I would add that if you're using API Kit, and you want to return a 404, the exception you should throw is: `org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException`. This will use the apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping so that you don't need to write any custom code to return the 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can use choice router after transformer to check `payload.event_ops_type == "400"`. Then either raise custom exception for exception handling or set response status and reason based on `event_ops_type` 400.